# Laravel Filesystem: obtain default directory similar to Storage::path

Tags: laravel, filesystems

I need to get default filesystem folder usually returned by Storage::path($fileName) as part of whole path including file name also. $fileName here is required parameter, unfortunately.

How to get default filesystem folder without $fileName ?

Comment: How about `Storage::path('')`?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Storage::path('') returns default filesystem root folder